# users created in redis delete if redis pod delete/restart

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, bitnami

i have deployed a single/standalone redis container using bitnami/redis helm chart.
i created a new user in redis by connecting to redis using redis-cli and running command "ACL SETUSER username on allkeys +@all +SADD >password" and the user created is shown by ACL LIST.
Now if delete the redis pod, new pod will comeup and it doesnot have the user created above by me.
why this is happening ?
how to create permanent users in redis?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your redis implementation uses the [regular redis implementation](https://redis.io/docs/manual/security/acl/), then there are two options for ACL persistence:

1. in the main redis configuration file, or
2. in an external ACL configuration file

This is determined by whether you have an `aclfile` configuration option set. If you're using the first version, then `CONFIG REWRITE` should update the server configuration; if you're using the second version, `ACL SAVE` is what you need. If you don't issue either of these, your ACLs will be lost when the server next restarts.

Comment: when i run ACL SAVE, it gives error "(error) ERR This Redis instance is not configured to use an ACL file."
This means i havenot used aclfile for configuration, how to use external aclfile for creating users in redis in bitnami/redis helm chart?